# asp.net mvc web app that prompt user to confirm decision step by step

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using asp.net mvc and in my web app users will be prompted in multiple steps to acquire information or to cancel (or go back) the action mid way. Can someone recommend an implementation way to tackle this. 
Should I use a 1 action method per prompt ? 
Or should I do every prompt in javascript on the client side ?
Or any other approaches will be welcomed .

Comment: what details you need in prompts? is it just confirmation?

Comment: You may consider the option to put which step is currently the user on in a cookie. Server side you can take decision which action to redirect the user to, or which view to render. depends if you want to have one action or multiple actions.

Comment: How many steps will you be expecting your users to go through?

Comment: one use case is : user fill in a form and attached some text file. The form is then submited. Depending on values in the submitted form , the user will be prompted for permission to extract data from the attachments  ( or the user can deny server to extract). If data from attachments are extracted, the user will be prompted to confirm the extracted result ( even allow user to do some editing) . Validation are required on all data so the user will be prompt to correct any problems or allow to abandon the whole submit.

Comment: @dan_l Have you considered marking an answer as accepted?

Comment: @miscusermandude sorry for the delay . answer is accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the details from your comment, it seems like the best solution would be to simply break everything up into separate Actions as you mentioned in your original question.

The reason behind this is that you have 'a lot' going on at each step, you are likely to want more than just client-side validation at each step, and you may want to prepare for the situation where someone's browser fails (or they just close it for some reason) at some point between the beginning and end of the process - you may want them to be able to pick up where they left off.

It would likely be easier to manage all of the steps on your end and keep things feeling 'solid' as your users move through the process if you keep everything as separate actions.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the jQuery formwizard plugin: http://thecodemine.org/

You just have one controller action / one View with a big form and split the form into pages by defining a div for each step.